# Standardize values for each unique group separately

Tags: r, group-by, scale

The dataset "df" exists of the following two variables:

```
SessionID   TotalMark
14  50
14  5
14  54
14  55
17  96
17  63
17  78
17  25
17  98
```

Now I would like to standardise TotalMark for each group of SessionIDs separately so group by(SessionID) and put these standardised scores in a new variable StandTotalMark. This is the desired result:

```
SessionID   TotalMark   StandTotalMark
14  50  0.373490072
14  5   -1.493960286
14  54  0.539485659
14  55  0.580984556
17  96  0.8024557
17  63  -0.3009209
17  78  0.2006139
17  25  -1.5714758
17  98  0.8693270
```

I did achieve the desired result but I was wondering if anyone can come up with an elegant one line solution in R without having to use a for loop? I used the scale function to standardise the TotalMark

Comment: Please include the code you wrote that you need help improving. R is setup so you rarely need a for loop for operations like this—part of the language's power is in operating on vectors

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  group_by(SessionID) %>% 
  mutate(StandTotalMark=scale(TotalMark))
```

tested with

```
dd <- read.table(text="SessionID   TotalMark
14  50
14  5
14  54
14  55
17  96
17  63
17  78
17  25
17  98", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution using `by`

```
df$StandTotalMark <- unlist(by(df, df$SessionID, FUN = function(x) scale(x$TotalMark)))
df;
#  SessionID TotalMark StandTotalMark
#1        14        50      0.3734901
#2        14         5     -1.4939603
#3        14        54      0.5394857
#4        14        55      0.5809846
#5        17        96      0.8024557
#6        17        63     -0.3009209
#7        17        78      0.2006139
#8        17        25     -1.5714758
#9        17        98      0.8693270
```

Note there seems to be a mistake in the scaled numbers for `SessionID=17` from your expected output.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "SessionID   TotalMark
14  50
14  5
14  54
14  55
17  96
17  63
17  78
17  25
17  98", header = T)
```

Comment: Yes my mistake, thanks for noticing it.  I have changed it!

Answer (score 0):

Also doable using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = rep(1:20, 5), 
                 value = sample(60:100, size = 100, replace = T)) 

dt[,.StandValue := scale(value, center = T, scale = T), by = id]

head(dt)
```